# Storage of history values for a key in CouchDB

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How does the state database(couchDB) store data if the putState(key,value) overrides the existing value? Since we are able to fetch the history using GetHistoryForKey()....this means the old value is still existing in the state DB?

Comment: Because CouchDB is append-only storage it does not delete/replace old values. It is in the docs, read about how the winning revision is determined. There are two ways to delete history, 1) compact database, 2) replicate database. In second case replica will have only leaf revisions.

Comment: @bamanow thanks a lot for the reply.I found that the block chain maintains the history at block level and hence with GetHistoryForKey() function i get the transaction history and not from the state DB. The state DB (here couchDB) maintains the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Only the latest value of a key is stored in the CouchDB state database.

The full history of keys and values are stored in the blockchain data structure itself. When GetHistoryForKey() is called, an index is consulted that identifies all the transactions that have updated a key, and then these transactions are queried from the blockchain data structure to return the history of keys and values.